Messaging unqualified id with a method that is possibly direct



enter image description here
2.
enter image description here
error is Messaging unqualified id with a method that is possibly direct
and Multiple methods named 'initWithValue:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes
I'm using realm and I get an error like this. Please help me

It’s a Best Practice here on SO to include code, errors and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. If the links break, it would invalidate the question. Also, images and links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at No Images Please. Finally, there are no errors shown so we don't know what the problem is.
